# When I click on menuItem of p:menu, the URL is building wrong

Tags: jsf, primefaces

when I click on my menuItem from my Menu (primefaces 5.1) open page well, but the next time and the other menuItem, the URL build wrong, i.e

the firs time when I click, open

`../project/subproject1/page1.jsf`

and if I click to another item, it make the URL like that

`../project/subproject1/subproject2/page2.jsf`

and do same with others

`../project/subproject1/subproject3/page3.jsf`

I use,

- Glassfish 4
- Eclipse Luna
- JSF 2.2

My code

index.xhtml

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west"
              size="200" header="Ocultar"
              collapsible="true">

    <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="false" />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

menu.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:menu model="#{controlador.model}" style="font-size:14px;" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

controlador.model (control is my bean) give me a list from data base and I check that is well. How I fix it.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: ok, mmmm when I click on menu (of primefaces) the first time I can see my page because the URL its build well but the second try the page save one part of the previous URL and obviously dont find the page, i.e. 

first click and one menuItem 
http//XXXX/project/subproject1/page1.jsf

second click and one menuItem
http//XXXX/project/subproject1/subproject2/page1.jsf

Comment: Well, you are using a programmatic menu, but you are not showing the code that creates and controls the menu. You should post that and also refer to the primefaces showcase examples.

Comment: My partner solved setting in the bean of that pages, like this setUrl("../../carpetPages/subCarpetPages/"+menu.getPArameterUrl()); something like this. thanks anyway Nicholas

Comment: In the future, please post your questions so they can be answered.

Comment: Ok Nicholas I'll do it!